# Ive lost my phone how do i install an app on that stolen phone from my pc or laptop

Tags: backup, lost-phone, google

Im working in the DRC an sombody stole my Samsung Gallaxy S4 from my car I want to block the phone so he cant use it any more

Comment: I've just added the `lost-phone` tag to your question. Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info), which completely answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed [Android Device Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=en) or [Avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.at_play&hl=en) (or similar) anti-theft agent apps, you can lock/erase your phone through internet.

If you are lucky enough that the user is using WiFi/3G using same (your) google account, you can even download these (or any other) apps remotely using [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store).

If none of the above going to work, just report to your service provider, they'll block the phone.